# Identity involving the zeta function

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory

This might be very trivial, but a proof I'm reading on the bounds of the zeta-function uses the following fact:

If $s=\sigma+it$ is a complex number and if $\sigma\geq 2$, then $|\zeta(s)|\geq 1-\displaystyle\sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{1}{n^2}$.

What would be a rigorous explanation of this? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just the triangle inequality together with $\lvert n^{s}\rvert = n^{\operatorname{Re} s}$ and the monotonicity of $\sigma \mapsto n^\sigma$. Thus we have

\begin{align}
\lvert \zeta(s)\rvert &= \Biggl\lvert 1 + \sum_{n = 2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s}\Biggr\rvert\\
&\geqslant 1 - \Biggl\lvert \sum_{n = 2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s}\Biggr\rvert\\
&\geqslant 1 - \sum_{n = 2}^\infty \frac{1}{\lvert n^s\rvert}\\
&= 1 - \sum_{n = 2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^\sigma}\\
&\geqslant 1 - \sum_{n = 2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}.
\end{align}